# Exception when starting server

Tags: jax-ws

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
                at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:665)
                at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:472)
                at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:298)
                at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:234)
                at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:81)
                at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:64)
                at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:63)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:1869)
                at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:1826)
                at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:1806)
                at java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class.java:1900)
                at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(RuntimeModeler.java:1397)
                at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:161)
                at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:467)
                at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:333)
                at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:45)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
            ... 76 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with a similar problem; do you use any common libary e.g. something that is loaded from inside container?

For example our server.xml looks like this:

```
<classloader commonLibraryRef="EclipseLinkLib" delegation="parentLast"/>
```

We got a similar exception, see: [Missing NamedQueries annotation in WAS Liberty enviroment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725311/missing-namedqueries-annotation-in-was-liberty-enviroment)
By changing the delegation to `parentFirst` the app started just fine.